# C++ Program with Perfomance Tool - Leaks

Tags: c++, performance, memory-leaks, xcode3.2

```
int main (int argc, char * const argv[])
{
    int *num = new int[100] ;
    return 0;
}
```

In the above program, there are defintely *memory leaks*. But when **Run -> Run with Performance Tool -> Leaks**, gives the following figure which shows no leaked objects. What am I missing? Do the performance tool work only for *Objective C* environment ?

[image]

**Edit:**

On an MSVC++ 2010, it is easy to detect leaks while running on an debug mode -

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>

int main (int argc, char * const argv[])
{
    int *num = new int[100] ;

    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();   // Looking for something equivalent to this
                             // that lets me know whether the program has
                             // memory leaks on an XCode environment.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are running in release with full optimization?

Comment: @Naveen - I am running in Debug mode but not sure about *full optimization*. Will check it.

Comment: @Naveen - Optimization Level -> None.

Comment: If it's optimized, I could see a compiler just tossing that `new` statement.

Comment: Not really related, but seems, there is some Valgrind port to Mac: http://www.sealiesoftware.com/valgrind/

Answer (score 2):

`leaks` doesn't perform a post-mortem dump of blocks that weren't freed.

Instead it analyzes the process while it's running and looks for allocated blocks that are no longer accessible.  It scans either on demand or every 10 seconds.

Change your program to something like the following:

```
int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) 
{
    int *num = new int[100] ;
    char c;

    puts("memory allocated\npress a key to continue...\n");
    c = getchar();

    num = NULL; // leak the allocation

    puts("memory has been leaked\npress a key to continue...\n");
    c = getchar();

    return 0; 
}
```

And if you have the scan occur while the program is waiting for the 2nd keypress it should detect the leak.

Comment: Is there something like this for xcode equivalent to vs c++ 2010. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf.aspx

Comment: @Mahesh: you might try Wu Yongwei's open source debug allocator: http://wyw.dcweb.cn/leakage.htm - I've not tried it, so can't vouch for it, but the article indicates a lot of thought has gone into it.